# PHP and MySQL string comparison failing

Tags: php, mysql, string, comparison

Okay, so I'm having a pretty annoying little problem with my php code. Basically I pull two variables from two seperate sources. One's a cookie and the other is from a MySQL database.

```
$data = explode("|", $_COOKIE['login']);
$sql = "SELECT session_id FROM users WHERE username='user1'";
$result = $data->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$test1 = $data[0];
$test2 = $row['session_id'];

If($test1 == $test2) {
  // Do some stuff
}
else {
  // Don't do some stuff
}
```

The actual string is:

x6vkYu6Ep^lm(1Rdm)5Gj5Hj7ilL6FsDL88JC#n@iTyBUqYgJ48#9Ow%*2ZdGs1rA8bc)JoCD7dywcZgg7soV0D#!DpR^pjQwF#QpBt#HRKe$JEtQ*3LhFXsjmkzWNpt

The string is randomly generated before being stored from the following character set:
1234567890!@#$%^&*()abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

```
for($i = 0; $i < 128; $i++) {
  $string .= $char_set[rand(0, strlen($char_set)-1)];
}
$sql = "UPDATE users SET session_id='$string' WHERE user='user1'";
$data->query($sql);
setcookie('login', $string . "|" . $username);
```

If I just set the two variables equal to the above string and evaluate, it works out just fine. Also, if I echo both $data[0] and $row['session_id'] the entire string will display, and they look indentical.

The if() statement will work if I use basic strings, like a number, or basic word, so I'm guessing it's due to special characters, but I don't know where in the proccess it goes wrong. As I said, if I set two variables to that string value, it evaluates, but when I pull from MySQL and the cookie, despite that both strings look the same, it won't evaluate.

Any thoughts?

Comment: php creates its own session id, why not just use that?

Comment: These might be typos from posting here, but both snippets have mismatched quotes: the first on line 2, the second on line 4

Comment: First of all, you need to close your sql query at the end with double quotation. $sql = "SELECT session_id FROM users WHERE username='user1'"; Secondly,... try to do the comparison with If($test1 === $test2). Cheers

Comment: I fixed the quotes, sorry, just a typo.I also tried using if($test1 === $test2) and it still fails.